# Opening a local HTML file

Tags: android, html, layout, webview

I have a textview in a layout (called - t_c) with the code:-

```
      <TextView
      android:id="@+id/GoToTCContacting"
      android:layout_width="360dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:background="@drawable/border2"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:onClick="GoToTCContacting"
      android:padding="10dp"
      android:text="Contacting"
      android:textColor="#FFF"
      android:textSize="18sp" />
```

I want the textview to open another layout (called - t_c_contacting) on click which has a webview in and that webview to open a html file I have in my layout folder called con.html.

This is how the t_c_contacting layout is coded:-

```
 <WebView
 android:id="@+id/contactingView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This is how my class is set up to open t_c_contacting which works fine but I can't work out how to populate the webview with my file.

```
    public void GoToTCContacting(View view)  
{  
    setContentView(R.layout.t_c_contacting); 
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is how to code the html call

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the HTML stored localy, simply call:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl, mHtmlData, MIME_TYPE, CHARSET, "");
```

Where:

`mUrl` can be a dummy Url if you want, or the actual URL of the page, so the WebView can figure out how to place some UI elements such as Images.

`mHtmlData` is a String that contains the actual HTML content.

`MIME_TYPE` is a String that represents the mimeType of the data, say: `"text/html"`

`CHARSET` is a String that represents the encoding of the data, say: `"utf-8"`

I hope that helps.